# How did these entries get into the Public DNS?

Tags: dns

try ping these (and everything in between)
021111111111
021555555555

What are they?

Comment: They are NOT IN DNS AT ALL. They are IPv4 _ADDRESSES_ in a long-obsolete format that is often used by spammers and (other) criminals to confuse or deceive people. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_addr.html

Answer (score 4):

They are IPv4 addresses, nothing special.

An IPv4 is a 32 bits integer. It is often written as a sequence of 4 octets but can as well be written in a full number.

In fact, `ping` does even do the job for you:

```
$ ping 021111111111
PING 021111111111 (137.36.146.73): 56 data bytes
```

So `021111111111` is just another way to write `137.36.146.73`
Why? Starting with 0 it is an octal number, base 8. If you convert it in decimal it is 2300875337 in decimal or in binary:

```
1000 1001
0010 0100
1001 0010
0100 1001
```

which translates as
137
36
146
73
and hence `137.36.146.73` is the usual representation.

Same for the other one that you can try to decode the same way.

Or have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations for extended discussion and references.